# How to deserialize this json file in vb.net with json.net?

Tags: json, vb.net

I am using the json.net library and I have this json file I want to deserialize:

```
{
"jsonVersion": 3,
"levelMasteryScore3": 70000,
"boosts": {
"preBoostSupergems": {
  "enabled": 1,
  "jsonVersion": 1
},
"preBoostThreeMoves": {
  "enabled": 1,
  "jsonVersion": 1
},
"preBoostColorSplash": {
  "enabled": 1,
  "jsonVersion": 1,
  "excludedColors": [
    "G"
  ]
},
"jsonVersion": 1
},
"name": "0017",
"moveLimitObjective": {
"moveLimit": 19,
"jsonVersion": 1
},
"gemSpawnChance": {
"R": 20,
"B": 20,
"G": 0,
"P": 20,
"Y": 20
},
"levelMasteryScore1": 20000,
"board": {
"tiles": [
  [
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X"
  ],
  [
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X"
  ],
  [
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X",
    "X"
  ],
  [
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A"
  ],
  [
    "A",
    "E",
    "A",
    "E",
    "A",
    "E",
    "A"
  ],
  [
    "A",
    "J1",
    "A",
    "J1",
    "A",
    "J1",
    "A"
  ],
  [
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A",
    "A"
  ],
  [
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "E",
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1"
  ],
  [
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1",
    "J1"
  ]
],
"visibleSize": {
  "width": 7,
  "jsonVersion": 1,
  "height": 9
},
"pieces": [
  [
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@"
  ],
  [
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@"
  ],
  [
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@",
    "@"
  ],
  [
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D"
  ],
  [
    "D",
    " ",
    "D",
    " ",
    "D",
    " ",
    "D"
  ],
  [
    "D",
    " ",
    "D",
    " ",
    "D",
    " ",
    "D"
  ],
  [
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D",
    "D"
  ],
  [
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " "
  ],
  [
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " ",
    " "
  ]
],
"jsonVersion": 2
},
"levelMasteryScore2": 50000,
"jellyObjective": {
"jellyToRemove": 16,
"jsonVersion": 1
 }
}
```

It looks really complex to me and I want to retrieve the following elements:

- `moveLimitObjective": {
  "moveLimit": 19,
  "jsonVersion": 1`
- `"gemSpawnChance": {
  "R": 20,
  "B": 20,
  "G": 0,
  "P": 20,
  "Y": 20
  }`
- the '**board**' block with the '**tiles**' and '**pieces**' blocks
- `"jellyObjective": {
  "jellyToRemove": 16,
  "jsonVersion": 1
  }`

I've seen plenty of examples over the web, but I can't figure it out. I don't even know where to begin.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

Use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert the json data to csharp classes and then convert the resulting code to vb.net using [another converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

Once you have your classes in vb.net that model the data you're trying to get from the JSON, you can use JSON.NET's deserialize object method and grab the properties you want. For example:

Assuming you've set up your .NET classes that model the json objects. i'll call the top-level object `Game`.

```
Dim json As String
Dim game As Game = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Game)(json)
MessageBox.Show(game.GemSpawnChance)
```

Something close to that should work.

This example provides some direction, but doing more research will be helpful. Maybe start with the [Newtonsoft.Json page](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Comment: Here's another nice converter that will output to your language of choice: http://jsontodatacontract.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Wow, that converter tool is really handy. Just one more thing: what do I do with the output? Do I add it to my project?

Comment: Yeah, you can add it as a new class (in a file) to  your project.

Comment: thank you. As I said, I am a complete beginner to json. So, let's say I want to messagebox the elements of  'gemSpawnChance', how do you do it?

Comment: Sorry i missed this, i've edited my answer to provide more detail.